# Split data in a single column

Tags: python, pandas

Scenario:

Using pandas to read a csv. Problem is all the columns and the data is present in a single column in the csv file.

CSV format (A is a column in the CSV):

```
    A
"c1   c2"
"19   91"
```

Code Tried:

```
data = pd.read_csv("/test.csv")
print (data.head())
```

Op:

```
 c1\c2\c3\c4\c5\c6\c7\
 19910710\t111\t22...
```

Required Op:

```
c1   c2      c3  
000  222    333
```

The format of the csv is all the columns and values are present in a single column "A" separated by "SPACE". Since there is a "SPACE" separating, the values are getting prefixed with "t". Is there any shortcut to get the required output.

Any suggestions are helpful

Comment: Looks more like its tab-delimited to me, as `\t` is the escape sequence for a tab..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution:

```
data = pd.read_csv("test.csv", delim_whitespace=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

If each column is being separated by a \, you might want to do, `data = pd.read_csv("/test.csv", sep='\')` then since you wanted to select those three specifically I would do,

```
data = pd.read_csv("/test.csv")
my_data = data['c1', 'c2', 'c3']
print (my_data)
```

Comment: Would just change it to '\\' instead

Comment: @akaJengo the csv is not separated by "/". It is separated by " " (SPACE) and when I try to read this csv pandas prefix the column names and data with a "/" and "t".

Comment: @Fred the csv is not separated by "/". It is separated by " " (SPACE) and when I try to read this csv pandas prefix the column names and data with a "/" and "t".